How to prevent Native Javascript from redirecting a <button>?
I want to modify a button on a website that is accessed with webview, because the button on the website opens a page with a new tab / window.
<div>
  <button>
    <span>Button Name</span>
  </button>
</div>

*As a note, the <button> does not have a, href, data-url inline
I don't want that, I want the button to open the link in the same window / tab, for performance reasons.
I have tried implementing customJS to MainActivity.java, it successfully redirects to a custom URL as a test.
function setupButtonObserver(targetNode) {
  const buttonActions = {
    "/link1": ["1LanguageA", "1LanguageB"],
    "/link2": ["2LanguageA", "2LanguageB"],
  };

  document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const button = event.target.closest('button');
    if (button) {
      for (const [url, texts] of Object.entries(buttonActions)) {
        if (texts.some(text => button.textContent.includes(text))) {
          event.preventDefault();
          window.open(url, '_self');
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  });

  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
      if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
          if (node.nodeType === 1) {
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(targetNode, { childList: true, subtree: true });
}
setupButtonObserver(document.body);

But it still opens a New Tab / Window. When I press "Back", then the Custom URL test appears which opens in the same Tab / Window as the webview.
So the current condition is, when pressing 1 button, 2 URLs open on different Tabs/Window. (1 opens in the same tab/window, and 1 more opens in a new tab/window).
Then I have also tried to add this:
function disableTargetBlank() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_blank"]');

  links.forEach(link => {
    link.removeAttribute('target');
  });
}

window.onload = function() {
  disableTargetBlank();
};

const lihatblank = new MutationObserver(() => {
  disableTargetBlank();
});

lihatblank.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

But it seems to be due to a conflict with the JavaScript function that already exists on the website.
In addition there is a function:
("a", {
className: "underline",
href: "/link",
target: "_blank",
rel: "noopener noreferrer",
children: "here"
})

There is also a native function that manages:
onClick: () => {
  window.open("/link")
}

Both are in different Javascript files.
So is there a way to prevent Native Javascript from redirecting <button>?

This question is similar to: Open URL in same window and in same tab. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
